# Consolidating column data from number of CSV files into a single CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, merge

I am new to Python, especially data handling. This is what I am trying to achieve-

I run CIS test on several servers and produce a CSV file for each server (file name is the same as the server name). The output file from all servers is copied to a central server
The output produced looks like below (Truncated output)-

```
File1: dc1pp1v01.co.uk.csv
Description,Outcome,Result
1.1 Database Placement,/var/lib/mysql,PASSED
1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account,mysql,PASSED
1.3 Diable MySQL history,Not Found,PASSED

File2: dc1pp2v01.co.uk.csv
Description,Outcome,Result
1.1 Database Placement,/var/lib/mysql,PASSED
1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account,mysql,PASSED
1.3 Diable MySQL history,Not Found,PASSED

File..n: dc1pp1v02.co.uk.csv
Description,Outcome,Result
1.1 Database Placement,/var/lib/mysql,PASSED
1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account,mysql,PASSED
1.3 Diable MySQL history,Found,FAILED
```

What I want is that output should look like-

```
Description  dc1pp1v01 dc1pp2v01 dc1pp1v02 
0  1.1 Database Placement PASSED   PASSED   PASSED
1  1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account PASSED   PASSED   PASSED
2  1.3 Diable MySQL history PASSED   PASSED   FAILED
```

To merge these files, I have created another file with only Description field in it and two-column heading as below-

```
file: cis_report.csv
Description,Result
1.1 Database Placement,
1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account,
1.3 Diable MySQL history,
```

I have written below code to do column-based merge-

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd 

col_list = ["Description","Result"]
path = "/Users/Python/Data"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "dc*.csv"))

cis_df = pd.read_csv("/Users/Python/Data/cis_report.csv")

for fl in all_files:
   d = pd.read_csv(fl, usecols=col_list)
   f = cis_df.merge(d, on='Description')
   cis_df = f.copy()
   
print(cis_df.head())
```

The output I am getting is-

```
Description Result_x Result_y Result_x Result_y
0                      1.1 Database Placement      NaN   PASSED   PASSED   PASSED
1  1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account      NaN   PASSED   PASSED   PASSED
2                    1.3 Diable MySQL history      NaN   PASSED   PASSED   FAILED
```

In my code, I am not sure how I get the file name as a header for the result and get rid of NaN.

Also, is there a better way of achieving the output I am looking for without using dummy file(cis_report.csv)? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `DataFrme.pivot()` function.
The code below is well commented and a fully working example. Make changes as you need

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Get all file names in a directory
# Use . to use current working directory or replace it with
# e.g. r'C:\Users\Dames\Desktop\csv_files'
file_names = os.listdir('.')

# Filter out all non .csv files
# You can skip this if you know that only .csv files will be in that folder
csv_file_names = [fn for fn in file_names if fn[-4:] == '.csv']

# This Loads a csv file into a dataframe and sets the Server column
def load_csv(file_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    df['Server'] = file_name.split('.')[0]
    return df

# Append all the csvfiles after being processed by load_csv
df = pd.DataFrame().append([load_csv(fn) for fn in csv_file_names])

# Turn DataFrame into Pivot Table
df = df.pivot('Description', 'Server', 'Result')

# Save DataFrame into CSV File
# If this script runs multiple times make sure that the final.csv is saved elsewhere!
# Or it will be read by the code above as an input file
df.to_csv('final.csv')
```

The final DataFrame looks like this

```
Server                                     dc1pp1v01 dc1pp1v02 dc1pp2v01
Description
1.1 Database Placement                        PASSED    PASSED    PASSED
1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account    PASSED    PASSED    PASSED
1.3 Diable MySQL history                      PASSED    FAILED    PASSED
```

And the CSV file like this

```
Description,dc1pp1v01,dc1pp1v02,dc1pp2v01
1.1 Database Placement,PASSED,PASSED,PASSED
1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account,PASSED,PASSED,PASSED
1.3 Diable MySQL history,PASSED,FAILED,PASSED
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd 

col_list = ["Description","Result"]
path = "/Users/Python/Data"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "dc*.csv"))

cis_df = pd.read_csv("/Users/Python/Data/cis_report.csv")
from functools import reduce
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Description'), [cis_df]+[pd.read_csv(i, usecols=col_list) for i in all_files])
df_final.drop([i for i in df_final.columns if 'Outcome' in i], axis=1).rename(columns={i:j for i,j in zip([i for i in df_final.columns if 'Result' in i], [i.replace('.co.uk.csv','') for i in all_files])})
```

**Output**

```
    Description dc1pp1v01   dc1pp2v01   dc1pp1v02
0   1.1 Database Placement  PASSED  PASSED  PASSED
1   1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account  PASSED  PASSED  PASSED
2   1.3 Diable MySQL history    PASSED  PASSED  FAILED
```

Comment: Sorry but I am still getting same output as with my original script. If I put a print statement before the last line in your script, the output is still the same. The issue seems to be with the last line. 

I have Pythong 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to do it on my own. Below solution works for me but I am sure there are more concise way of doing it-

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd 
from functools import reduce

col_list = ["Description","Result"]
path = "/Users/Python/Data"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "dc*.csv"))

final_cols = ['Description']
for j in all_files:
    final_cols.append(os.path.basename(j).split('.',1)[0]) 

cis_df = pd.read_csv("/Users/Python/Data/cis_report.csv")

df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Description'), [cis_df]+[pd.read_csv(i, usecols=col_list) for i in all_files])
df_final.rename(columns=dict(zip(df_final.columns,final_cols)),inplace=True)

print(df_final.head())
```

I made a small change in the description holding file. Removed result field and the ',' at the endo each line

file: cis_report.csv

```
Description
1.1 Database Placement
1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account
1.3 Diable MySQL history
```

The output I get is-

```
Description dc1pp1v01 dc1pp2v01 dc2pp1v01
0                      1.1 Database Placement        PASSED        PASSED        PASSED
1  1.2 Use dedicated least privilaged account        PASSED        PASSED        PASSED
2                    1.3 Diable MySQL history        PASSED        PASSED        FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a winner, nevertheless:

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/Users/Python/Data')

# Read the reports and store the results in a 2-dim list
results = []
for file in path.glob('dc*.co.uk.csv'):
    with open(file, 'r') as fin:
        results += [[file.name.split('.')[0]]
                    + [row[2] for row in csv.reader(fin)][1:]]

# Read the row labels
with open(path / 'cis_report.csv', 'r') as fin:
    labels = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(fin)]

# Prepare the output
output = [[label] + [result[i] for result in results]
          for i, label in enumerate(labels)]

# Write the output
with open(path / 'cis_reports_merged.csv', 'w') as fout:
    csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t').writerows(output)
```